# Modifying YouTube API iframe subscribe counter

Tags: youtube-api

I want to modify the following code for a YouTube subscribe button with counter, so that after subscribing, or if you are already subscribed, the button can be clicked to take you to the YouTube page in question.

```
<iframe data-gapiattached="true" frameborder="0" hspace="0" marginheight="0"
  marginwidth="0" scrolling="no"
  src="https://www.youtube.com/subscribe_embed?bsv&amp;usegapi=1&amp;channel=SingularityUtopia"
  style="height: 24px; left: 0px; margin: 0px; position: static; top: 0px;
  visibility: visible; width: 170px;" tabindex="0" vspace="0" width="100%">
</iframe>
```

Also in Firefox I see a blueish possible box-shadow, to the right of the button at the left pointer of the count-box. It occurs after clicking subscribe or unsubscribe (focus?), and I want to remove that.

Answer (score 0):

That click isn't possible since the subscribe button is coming from an external source in this case www-subscribe-embed-vflxZ9bg5.js

Another question, where did you find this button ?

**UPDATE:**

This is not the right embed code. It should be

```
<div class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channel="CHANNELNAME"></div>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
```

Read more here [iframe www.youtube.com/subscribe_embed? google plus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17698628/iframe-www-youtube-com-subscribe-embed)

Comment: I originally found the button on the Radiohead site. Via this page https://google-developers.appspot.com/youtube/youtube_subscribe_button_fde582c03cec38236c694d6550bd6892.frame I have just generated the following code, which seems best.<br>

    `<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script> <div class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channel="SingularityUtopia" data-layout="full"></div>`